# Best practice when returning a wildcard List in java

Tags: java

I have a two functions that both return lists of similar database beans (they both implement the same interface, DbModel). I need to filter these lists in exactly the same way. I am relatively new to wildcards and was wondering if this is the correct approach. Any help/alternative methods would be much appreciated.

```
public PlayerStats<HittingStatsDb> getHittingSummaryStats(Integer playerId) {
        HittingStatsDbExample example = new HittingStatsDbExample();
        example.createCriteria().andPlayerIdEqualTo(playerId).andSplitKeyEqualTo(Constants.SplitKeys.REGULAR_SEASON);
        example.setOrderByClause("YEAR DESC");
        List<HittingStatsDb> dbList = (List<HittingStatsDb>) summaryFilter(hittingStatsDao.select(example));
        List<PlayerStatLine<HittingStatsDb>> statLineList = ListHelper.map(dbList, (statDb) -> new PlayerStatLine<HittingStatsDb>(statDb));

        return new PlayerStats<HittingStatsDb>(statLineList);
}

public PlayerStats<PitchingStatsDb> getPitchingSummaryStats(Integer playerId) {
    PitchingStatsDbExample example = new PitchingStatsDbExample();
    example.createCriteria().andPlayerIdEqualTo(playerId).andSplitKeyEqualTo(Constants.SplitKeys.REGULAR_SEASON);
    example.setOrderByClause("YEAR DESC");
    List<PitchingStatsDb> dbList = (List<PitchingStatsDb>) summaryFilter(pitchingStatsDao.select(example));
    List<PlayerStatLine<PitchingStatsDb>> statLineList = ListHelper.map(dbList, (statDb) -> new PlayerStatLine<PitchingStatsDb>(statDb));

    return new PlayerStats<PitchingStatsDb>(statLineList);
}

private List<? extends DbModel> summaryFilter(List<? extends DbModel> statLineList) {
    // Filter Logic
    return statLineList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return a wildcard type: use a constrained type variable:

```
private <T extends DbModel> List<T> summaryFilter(List<T> statLineList) {
  return statLineList;
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can continue use the result as a `List<SubclassOfDbModel>`: if you return `List<? extends DbModel>`, you can't do things like adding or setting items.

---

I encourage you to read *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 28, "Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility", which advises the use of bounded wildcards in parameters, but not in return values.

To make the parameter more flexible, you can use:

```
List<? extends T> statLineList
```

as the parameter; this just lets you do something like:

```
List<PitchingStatsDb> unfiltered = ...
List<DbModel> filtered = summaryFilter(unfiltered);
```

which you couldn't do with the code at the top, since `List<PitchingStatsDb>` isn't a subclass of `List<DbModel>`. It's a little bit more complication, for a little more flexibility; I leave it up to you to judge whether it is worth it for this code.

Comment: Does that expression in the angle brackets constrain all uses of T in that signature?

Comment: @AlbertOrlando yes. So the `T` in the return type is the same as the `T` in the parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndyTurner